# Homebrew: Arcane Duelist's Ward

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, homebrew-review

I'd like some feedback on an item for a campaign that is currently at level 10.

### **Arcane Duelist's Ward**

> As a bonus action, the bearer can speak a command word to cause two
> intricately inscribed stones into rise into the air for the next
> minute, shimmering into arcane shields. Two spinning shields of force
> orbit the bearer, catching their magical aura and whirring ever faster
> as they cast spells for the next minute.
>
> While in use, if the bearer is attack they can spend a reaction to
> make an arcana check dc of the attack roll. If the user succeeds, the
> whirling shields halt in the precise instant to deflect the blow,
> suddenly impenetrable walls of force. The shields diminish and cease
> rotating afterwards, but pick up speed again if the user casts at
> least three levels worth of spells. Similarly, expending 3 levels
> worth of spells once the duration is complete will recharge it for
> use.

https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/2952071-arcane-duelists-ward

Intended gameplay: There is an essence of martial skill to controlling the shields. The arcana roll makes for higher highs and lower lows, and incentivizes are riskier fast spell slinging style of combat to recharge the shield.
I'd love some feedback.

- This is for a single attack, and does not persist unlike shield.
- The dc blocked is unrelated to your current AC, it is purely arcana control.
- The spell levels do not need to come from one spell, it is cumulative.

Considering editing:

- arcana check dc of the attack roll (up to 25).
- dispel magic will discharge the stones, dropping them from the air.

Comment: It says "similarly", but it also says "expend" for recharging; do the spells still take effect? Who needs to cast/expend the spells to recharge it? Does this item require attunement? When do you decide to use the Reaction? Before or after you see the result of the attack roll? If you don't use the Reaction and the minute is up, is the Ward still expended and needs recharging? There's a bunch of questions left for this item, can you edit the description to make it clearer?

Comment: Hello. Are you a native English speaker? I am not, and I find your text bit hard to read and understand. Maybe I'm making other set of mistakes than you do in translation and that's the case? "whirring ever faster as they cast spells for the next minute" surely it is the bearer who cast spells, not walls? "if the bearer is attack" - I've read this as *attacking* and needed to go back and forth to figure out you meant *attacked*.  "The shields diminish and cease rotating afterwards" does it stay impenetrable? Or what is supposed to happen? P